# Store and retrieve .xml file in sqlite database in android

Tags: android

In my application I have downloaded .xml file from server and i want to store complete .xml file in my **sqlite** database and retrieve from it as .xml file.

See the example of .xml file

```
<soap:Envelope><soap:Body><Login_ValidateAuthenticatedUserResponse><Login_ValidateAuthenticatedUserResult><xs:schema id="NewDataSet"><xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true"><xs:complexType><xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"><xs:element name="Table1"><xs:complexType><xs:sequence><xs:element name="ReturnValue" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="UserId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/></xs:sequence></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:choice></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:schema><diffgr:diffgram><NewDataSet><Table1 diffgr:id="Table11" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted"><ReturnValue>100</ReturnValue><UserId>bc43c80d-061e-4683-9d2a</UserId></Table1></NewDataSet></diffgr:diffgram></Login_ValidateAuthenticatedUserResult></Login_ValidateAuthenticatedUserResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: your question is not clear.Please elaborate

Comment: Try taking a look at a [SAXparser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html) to parse the xml, and then put it into a database using [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't store a file directly in SQLite. Rather, parse the XML by using a [SAX parser](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/) or [DOM parser](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/), create a database with corresponding tag names as the table columns and then store the values according to their tag names in their respective columns.